# Finding flux out of cyllindrical surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Let $$D = (x,y,z) : (x^2 +y^2 \leq 1^2, 0 \leq z \leq 1)$$
>   Furthermore define 
>   $$\phi(x,y,z) = x^2 - y^2 + \frac{3}{2\pi}z^2$$
>   and  $$\boldsymbol{G}(x,y,z) =\frac{3}{\pi}zy\boldsymbol{i} + \arctan(x^2)\boldsymbol{j} + x^5 y \sqrt{z^2 +1}\boldsymbol{k}$$ Let the vector field **F** be defined by $$\boldsymbol{F}(x,y,z) = \nabla \phi + \nabla \times \boldsymbol{G} $$ Calculate the flux of **F** out of the cylindrical part of the surface of D.

Im supposed to use the divergence theorem, and the identity $\nabla \cdot(\nabla \times \boldsymbol{F}) = 0 \rightarrow$ (**div curl**$ = 0$) The expression for **F** is pretty awkward as its a function + a vector. Also not sure how Im supposed to use the identity and the smartest way to approach the problem.

Comment: $\nabla \phi$ is also a vector so $F$ isn't akward it is just a vector $+$ a vector.

Comment: What is $\nabla \phi $ actually? I thought it was just $\nabla \cdot \phi$.

Comment: It is the gradient of $\phi $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
$$\operatorname{div}(F)=\operatorname{div}(\nabla \phi+\nabla \times G)=\Delta \phi+\operatorname{div}(\nabla \times G)=\Delta \phi$$
and:
$$\Delta \phi=2-2+\frac{3}{\pi}$$
all it remains is to compute:
$$\int_D \operatorname{div}(F)=\int_D \frac{3}{\pi}=\frac{3}{\pi}\operatorname{Vol}(D)$$

---

It remains to compute the flux on the upper and lower part of the cylinder.

For $z=0$ this is:
$$\int_{x^2+y^2 \leq 1} F(x,y,0) \cdot (-\mathbf{k}) dx dy$$

But $$F \cdot \mathbf{k}=\nabla \phi \cdot \mathbf{k}+(\nabla \times G) \cdot \mathbf{k}=\partial_z \phi +(\partial_x G_y-\partial_y G_x)$$
here you obtain:
$$F \cdot \mathbf{k}=\frac{3}{2 \pi}\color{blue}{2} z +\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{3}{\pi} z$$

the $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ does not matter as it is independent of $z$ so it disappear when computing:

$$\int_{x^2+y^2 \leq 1} F(x,y,0) \cdot (-\mathbf{k}) dx dy+\int_{x^2+y^2 \leq 1} F(x,y,1) \cdot (\mathbf{k}) dx dy$$

Comment: What you wrote is correct. But for the question, we also need to subtract out the flux from the top and bottom parts of the cylinder (since the question asks for the flux through the cylindrical part).

Comment: Indeed I will modify my answer.

Comment: So does this mean flux out of the $z = 0$ circle is $0$ since $z= 0$ and the $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ goes away? Also Im assuming $\int_{x^2 + y^2 \leq 1} = \pi$ ?

Comment: Yes if you sum the fluxes at $z=0$ and $z=1$ the $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ goes away. The only term that remains is the $-3 \pi /2$ at $z=1$ and it is a constant so as you pointed out it is only $\pi \times (-3\pi/2)$ :-).

Comment: Don't you get $\frac{3}{2\pi} 1 - \frac{3}{\pi} 1 = \frac{-3}{2\pi} \pi$ from the $z = 1$ circle, then you have subtract that from $3$ which is the flux through the whole sylinder. So you get $3 - (-3/2) = \frac92$? This seems to be the wrong answer.

Comment: Do you mean before or after integrating over the disk ?

Comment: @Delta-u i edited my comment.

Comment: Indeed I have made a mistake, I will edit my answer.